# php category recursive hierarchy

Tags: php, recursion, categories

I have category hierarchy like this.

- 721 parent is 235
- 235 parent is 201
- 201 parent is 1
- 1  parent is 0

0 is the root category id, I am trying to build a function that input leaf id 721, get full path id of 721, 235, 201, 1

```
public function getPath($inputId = 0, $idList=array())
{       
    $sql ="SELECT * FROM hierarchy where id='{$inputId}'";
    $result = $this->db->fetchAll($sql);

    if($result){
        $currentId = $result[0]["id"];
        $parentId = $result[0]["parent_id"];

        $idList[] = $currentId;

        if ($parentId !=0){
           $this->getPath($parentId, $idList);
        }else{
            //var_dump($idList);
            return $idList;
        }
    }

}
```

I can see correct results in var_dump part above, but when I use this function from another class, it return null, like this
$data = $whateveHelper->getPath('721');

could anyone help?

Thanks

Comment: You’re not doing anything with the value returned from the recursive call of `getPath`.

Comment: Depending on your database, you may have extensions available for tree/graph data.  Similarly, if you're going to be doing heavy work with your trees, a stored procedure may be of value to you.

Answer (score 3):

You just need to change this:

```
if ($parentId !=0){
    $this->getPath($parentId, $idList);
}
```

to this:

```
if ($parentId !=0){
    return $this->getPath($parentId, $idList);
}
```

Then you need to remove the else clause and move the "return $idList;" line to the bottom of your function so it is always returned. Your code above would only return $idList in the event that the $parentId was 0. However, you need the function to always return something if you are calling it recursively.

I recommend something along these lines for your whole function:

```
public function getPath($inputId = 0, $idList=array())
{       
    $sql ="SELECT * FROM hierarchy where id='{$inputId}'";
    $result = $this->db->fetchAll($sql);

    if($result){
        $currentId = $result[0]["id"];
        $parentId = $result[0]["parent_id"];

        $idList[] = $currentId;

        if ($parentId !=0){
           return $this->getPath($parentId, $idList);
        }
    }
    return $idList;
}
```

Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: yes, you are right, I can't believe I missed that part. Thank you very much for your help here!

Answer (score 1):

The line:

```
$this->getPath($parentId, $idList);
```

Needs to be

```
return $this->getPath($parentId, $idList);
```